# Can I independently control volume of MIX and PHONES on the Behringer XENYX 1202 mixer?

Tags: mixer

I am total beginner in the world of audio gear and recently find myself learning to play the piano. As I mostly get to play in the evenings when the family are sleeping, I want to be able to use headphones to listen to both the piano, and the output from the tablet providing my training. I also would like to sometimes have the audio coming out of speakers.

To facilitate this I have:

- Roland FP10 piano
- [Alto Professional ZMX52](https://www.altoprofessional.com/products/zmx52)
- Edifier R1000T4 active speakers

[image: Alto Professional ZMX52]

The problem I discovered is that the ZMX52 `MAIN` volume knob also controls the `PHONES` output, so there's no way to have the speakers muted but the headphones on.

I've been looking at the [Behringer Xenyx 1202](https://www.behringer.com/behringer/product?modelCode=P0573) instead, but can't make out if it will do what I need.

[image: Behringer Xenyx 1202]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that mixer can do it but you could try utilising the FX sends as a secondary mix with an output before the main mix. The output would come from the FX Send socket and you may need a headphone amp to bring it up to a usable level.

EDIT: I was looking at the wrong mixer. I don't think the Alto has FX Send capabilities but you might want to experiment with the 'Aux Out' which could be independent of the main volume.
The FX Send solution could work with the Behringer but I think you'd be better off talking to a salesperson in a shop and explaining the problem you're trying to solve before committing to buy based on a post here.